# Is there an alternative to a TTL Index in MongoDB that won’t permanently delete documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am building a job board using Node.JS / MongoDB. After a job listing is purchased by the user, it is added to the database and, using a TTL index, it deletes after 30 days. I’m wondering if there’s a way to change a field vs. deleting the entire document? I ask because I would want to give the user the option to “renew” their listing after the expiration period. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: You can set up a periodic task in your application.

Comment: You can also just add a field called "renewalDate", initialize it to the create date and then query items that have a renewalDate that is less than 30 days back from now.  Then, to "renew" a listing, you just set the renewalDate to a more current date so it will appear in the query again.  You could then run a periodic task (once a night) to permanently delete any documents that are old enough that they aren't even eligible for renewal any more.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think this would do the trick. I could even keep the TTL Index to wipe out super old listings no longer eligible for renewal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a field called "renewalDate", initialize it to the create date and then query items that have a renewalDate that is less than 30 days back from now for items to display. Then, to "renew" a listing, you just set the renewalDate to a more current date so it will appear in the query again.

You could then run a periodic task (once a night or once a week) to permanently delete any documents that are old enough that they aren't even eligible for renewal any more.  Or you could use the TTL feature to manage this.